# How to use constant memory on several cuda devices

Tags: memory, cuda, constants, device

I'm trying to utilize two cuda devices I have (I'm now experimenting with GF 690GTX which is actually 2 separate devices), and my program uses constant memory to transfer data to the device.

I clearly understand what I should do with global memory to use it in two devices:

```
//working with device 0
cudaSetDevice(0);
void* mem_on_dev_0 = cudaMalloc(...);
cudaMemcpy(mem_on_dev_0, mem_on_host, ...);
kernel_call<<<...>>>(mem_on_dev_0);

//working with device 1
cudaSetDevice(1);
void* mem_on_dev_1 = cudaMalloc(...);
cudaMemcpy(mem_on_dev_1, mem_on_host, ...);
kernel_call<<<...>>>(mem_on_dev_1);
```

But when working with constant memory the ordinary way to use it is to declare the constant variable somewhere in the file and then use "Symbol"-functions to work with it:

```c
// What device this memory is on?
__device__ __constant__ float g_const_memory[CONST_MEM_SIZE];

// dev_func can be told to be called on any device
__global__ void dev_func()
{
    //using const memory
    float f = g_const_memory[const_index];
}

void host_func()
{
    //cudaSetDevice(0);  //any sense?
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(g_const_memory, host_mem, ...);
    dev_func<<<...>>>();
}
```

I've googled much before asking this question but I didn't find any answer. Is there really no way to do it?

Comment: In your first code snippet add cudaMemcpyToSymbol to both the cudaSetDevice(0) and cudaSetDevice(1) section. Each device has a copy of the CUmodule. When you call cudaMemcpyToSymbol it will look up the symbol based upon the active device. I responded in more detail in a previous stackoverflow question but I cannot find the question.

Comment: while it's not related to your question, the syntax you describe in the first code section for cudaMalloc is not correct.  cudaMalloc does not return a pointer that you can assign as you suggest.  Instead, the pointer must be passed by reference in the function parameters.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, you are surely right.

Comment: @GregSmith: Are you sure that cudaMemcpyToSymbol() responds to cudaSetDevice()? In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405463/constant-memory-on-multiple-gpus#comment18341348_13405463), the OP was able to fix his app by using a separate `__constant__` for each card.